bgfx ライブラリをMinGW32でビルドする手順が知りたい
質問内容
bgfx ライブラリ を MinGW32 でビルドしたいのですが、依存関係を含めたビルド手順がわかりません、
環境
Windows 10
mingw32-make
gcc, g++
参考サイト
bgfx github: https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx?tab=readme-ov-file
bgfx ドキュメント: https://bkaradzic.github.io/bgfx/build.html#windows
調べたこと
mingw32-make を実行すると以下のエラーが出ます
>mingw32-make
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
makefile:6: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
makefile:213: pipe: No error
Available targets:
'grep' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:16: help] Error 255

上記のようにドキュメントサイトの二つの依存関係も同じエラーが出ます
genie --with-tools --with-combined-examples --with-shared-lib --os=windows --gcc=mingw-gcc gmake コマンドを試すと以下が表示されるのですが、どうやらビルドはされていないようです。
> genie --with-tools --with-combined-examples --with-shared-lib --os=windows --gcc=mingw-gcc gmake
Set MINGW environment variable.
Building configurations...
Running action 'gmake'...
Done. Generated 0/22 projects.

その他、ドキュメントやgoogleで検索しましたが、手順がいまいち掴めず正当な方法がわかりません

makeが必要なので以下のサイトからダウンロードして環境パスを通してmakeが実行できるようにします
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libintl.htm
ビルド手順１ 依存関係
glfwが必要なので別途ビルドします
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw
cd glfw
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .
make

ビルド手順２: ビルド実行
以下の手順で行います, --recursiveコマンドで依存関係を再帰的に取得します
git clone --recursive https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx.cmake
cd bgfx.cmake
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
make


Prerequisites - Windowsに

Windows users download GnuWin32 utilities:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libintl.htm


とあるように事前に必要なツールをインストールします。

ちなみに

>mingw32-make
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
makefile:6: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
makefile:213: pipe: No error
Available targets:
'grep' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:16: help] Error 255


ですが、makefile 6行目
UNAME := $(shell uname)

でunameコマンドを実行しようとしたところcoreutilsがインストールされていないため実行できずに失敗しています。このため、OSを判別できず不適切な処理に突入しています。
次にmakefile 16行目
help:
    @echo Available targets:
    @grep -E "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+:.*?## .*$$" $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'

でヘルプメッセージの一環としてgrepを実行しようとして失敗しています。もしOSをWindowsと認識できていればヘルプメッセージの表示方法もgrepを使わない別の処理に切り替わっていました。つまり、このエラーは副次的なものですのでひとまず気にしなくてもいいでしょう。

ありがとうございます。質問ですが、make を実行するところまでは実行できたのですが、その後何を行えばいいのでしょうか？リファレンスサイトに手順の説明がなく困っています、bgfx\.build\projects\gmake-mingw-gccディレクトリ内にあるmakefileも実行しましたが、エラーになります。
